# Firebase push notifications permission

Tags: firebase, push-notification, permissions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I had push messages Firebase account for company, which was deleted during hacking attack.

I created new account already, but my question is how can I restore old customers, which agreed for notification on old project (which no longer exist)? Will browser forget old permission and restore it?